# Stream filter regex

Tags: java

```
List<File> fileListToProcess = Arrays.stream(allFolderPath)
                .filter(myFile -> myFile.getName().matches("archive_"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am filtering files which starts with "archive_" to process using regex and streams. This does not work. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: "This does not work." is not a problem description. What happens? How do you know?

Comment: `matches` means the whole string matches the given regular expression. You are looking for [`startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String's` `startsWith` method for this:

```
List<File> fileListToProcess = Arrays.stream(allFolderPath)
                .filter(myFile -> myFile.getName().startsWith("archive_"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**OR**
You can use following regex to check if your string starts with `archive_`:

> ^(archive_).*

like:

```
List<File> fileListToProcess = Arrays.stream(allFolderPath)
                    .filter(myFile -> myFile.getName().matches("^(archive_).*"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```